# use Task parallel library for I/O bound processing

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Wondering if you could clarify.

I am writing a tool that all has todo is retrieve data from a database (sql server) and create txt files.
I am talking 500.000 txt files.

It's working and all is good.

However I was wondering if using Task Parallel library could improve and speed up the time it takes to create these files.

I know (read) that "TPL" is not meant to be used for I/0 bound processing and that most likely it will perform the same as
sequential .

Is this true?

Also in an initial attempt using a simple  "foreach parallel" I was getting an error cannot access file because is in use.

Any advice?

Comment: You could easily create a benchmark and see for yourself

Comment: Can you please post all of your code and **then** ask a specific question? "Is this true?" and "Any advice?" are not specific questions.

Comment: @Enigmativity I was not asking anybody to help with any code for starters,second mine was a very clear question which translated to you was "is there anypoint in putting in place some parallel coding when doing I/O bound processing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not parallel I/O bound processes.

The reason is simple: because CPU is not the bottleneck. No matter you start how many threads, You only have ONE disk to write to, and that is the slowest thing.

So what you need to is to simply iterate every file and write them. You can start a seperate working thread doing this work, or using async I/O to get a better UI response.

Answer (score 0):

If you read and/or write from multiple disks, then parallizing could improve speed. E.g if you want to read all your files and run a hash on them and store the hash, then you could create one thread per disk and you would see a significant speed up. However, if your case it seems like tasks are unlikely to improve performance.