# Using TPL with parallel blocking IO operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Preface: I'm aware that using the ThreadPool (either via `TPL` or directly) for IO operations [is generally frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058210/use-task-parallel-library-for-i-o-bound-processing) because IO is necessarily sequential, however my problem relates to "parallel IO" with blocking calls that don't expose an `Async` method.

I'm writing a GUI tool that fetches information about computers on the network that does this (simplified code):

```
String[] computerNames = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
foreach(String computerName in computerNames) {

    Task.Factory
        .StartNew( GetComputerInfo, computerName )
        .ContinueWith( ShowOutputInGui, RunOnGuiThread );

}

private ComputerInfo GetComputerInfo(String machineName) {

    Task<Int64>     pingTime  = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => GetPingTime( machineName ) );
    Task<Process[]> processes = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses( machineName ) );
    // and loads more

    Task.WaitAll( pingtime, processes, etc );

    return new ComputerInfo( pingTime.Result, processes.Result, etc );
}
```

When I run this code I'm finding it takes a surprisingly long amount of time to run compared to the old sequential code I had.

Note that each task in the `GetComputerInfo` method is entirely independent of others around it (e.g. Ping time can be computed separately from `GetProcesses`), yet when I inserted some `Stopwatch` timing calls, I discovered that the individual sub-tasks, like the `GetProcesses` call were only being started up to `3000ms` after `GetComputerInfo` had been called - there exists some large delay going on.

I noticed that when I reduce the number of outer parallel calls into `GetComputerInfo` (by reducing the size of the `computerNames` array) the first results were returned almost immediately. Some of the computer-names are for computers that are turned-off, so called to `GetProcesses` and `PingTime` take a very long time before timing out (my real code catches the exceptions). This is probably because the offline computers are blocking `Tasks` being run and the TPL naturally restricts it to my CPU hardware thread count (8).

Is there a way to tell TPL to not let the inner tasks (e.g. `GetProcesses`) block outer tasks (`GetComputerInfo`)?

(I've tried the "Parent/Child" task attachment/blocking, but it doesn't apply to my situation as I never explicitly attach child tasks to parent tasks, and the parent task naturally waits with `Task.WaitAll` anyway).

Comment: Probably would be better if `GetComputerInfo()` didnt have a `Task.WaitAll()` in it....sort of defeats the purpose.  Why not return `Task[]` ?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] reliably reproducing the issue, it's difficult if not impossible to diagnose the issue. That said, keep in mind that the thread pool does not have an unlimited number of threads waiting around for you. At idle, it will only have a handful of threads max (equal to # of CPU cores), and will only start new threads every half second to second (IIRC this is configurable and I don't recall the default). You might help things by a) using the async ping method, and b) using `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()` to boost the number of threads at idle, so they are ready when you want them.

Comment: Note that calling `SetMinThreads()` is a bit of a hack. It's unfortunate .NET doesn't have an async version of the `GetProcesses()` method; but I don't even see an async way to do it in native code. If you really want the operations to be in parallel, you're stuck managing the threads yourself, I think.

Comment: BTW, any reason you're not using `Task.Run()` and `await`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Where would the `await` call go?

Comment: @Dai, does this code runs on some event handler?

Comment: _"Where would the await call go?"_ -- you didn't provide enough context to be able to know. But generally speaking, it looks like both `GetComputerInfo()` and the method that calls it could be `async`, and use `await`. The caller can then call your `ShowOutputInGui()` method without any further complication, i.e. just as a regular program statement after the `await` completes.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have your `foreach` loop in some event handler, so first thing you should do is to mark it as `async` so you can call your other in async way. After that, you should introduce your `GetComputerInfo` to do `async` [all the way down](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

There are additional pitfalls in your code: [`StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), as it uses [`Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current.aspx) scheduler for tasks, rather than [`Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default.aspx) (so you need other overload). Unfortunately, that overload needs some more parameters, so the code will be not so simple. The good news is that you still need that overload to **tell the thread pool that your tasks are long running** so it should use a dedicated thread for them:

> [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx)
>
> Specifies that a task will be a long-running, coarse-grained operation involving fewer, larger components than fine-grained systems. It provides a hint to the `TaskScheduler` that oversubscription may be warranted.
>
> **Oversubscription lets you create more threads than the available number of hardware threads.** It also provides a hint to the task scheduler that **an additional thread might be required for the task** so that it does not block the forward progress of other threads or work items on the local thread-pool queue.

Also you should avoid the [`WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874.aspx) method as it is a blocking operation, so you have `1` thread less to do the actual work. You probably want to use [`WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874.aspx).

And finally, for returning your `ComputerInfo` result you can use the continuation with [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) usage, so your code could be something like this (cancellation logic also added):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// handle event in fire-and-forget manner
async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var computerNames = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
    foreach(String computerName in computerNames)
    {
        var compCancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // asynchronically wait for next computer info
        var compInfo = await GetComputerInfo(computerName, compCancelSource. Token);
        // We are in UI context here
        ShowOutputInGui(compInfo);
        RunOnGuiThread(compInfo);
    }
}

private Task<ComputerInfo> GetComputerInfo(String machineName, CancellationToken token)
{
    var pingTime = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        // action to run
        () => GetPingTime(machineName),
        //token to cancel
        token,
        // notify the thread pool that this task could take a long time to run,
        // so the new thread probably will be used for it
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
        // execute all the job in a thread pool
        TaskScheduler.Default);

    var processes = Task.Run(() => Process.GetProcesses(machineName), token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    // and loads more

    await Task.WhenAll(pingtime, processes, etc);
    return new ComputerInfo(pingTime.Result, processes.Result, etc);

    //var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ComputerInfo>();
    //Task.WhenAll(pingtime, processes, etc)
    //    .ContinueWith(aggregateTask =>
    //        if (aggregateTask.IsCompleted)
    //        {
    //            tcs.SetResult(new ComputerInfo(
    //                aggregateTask.Result[0],
    //                aggregateTask.Result[1],
    //                etc));
    //        }
    //        else
    //        {
    //            // cancel or error handling
    //        });

    // return the awaitable task
    //return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Why would `GetComputerInfo` use a continuation and tcs while `btn_Click` is async? `GetComputerInfo` should return `Task<ComputerInfo>`, btw.

Comment: This an async wrapper using TaskCompletionSource, please see Fig. 9 from linked MSDN article. Signature fixed, thank you.

Comment: `Task.Run` is the async wrapper, but `ContinueWith` is an abomination if the rest of the code uses `async`/`await`. `await Task.WhenAll(...); return new ComputerInfo(...);` would have been easier to write and is easier to read and understand.